# jQ hide all divs with custom attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some divs with my own data-attr, e.g:

```
<div tab="1" class="t-text">some text</div>
<div tab="2" class="t-text">some text</div>
```

How to find\select all divs that contain custom data attr "tab" with jQ?

Comment: jQuery `$('[tab]').hide()`, CSS `[tab] { display: none; }`

Comment: Don't use custom attributes. Use `data-tab` attribute instead.

Answer (score 0):

simply try with [has-attribute](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) selector

```
$( "div[tab]" ).hide();
```

if your attribute name is `data-tab` and actual markup is `<div tab="1" class="t-text">some text</div>`, then try

```
$( "div[data-tab]" ).hide();
```

Comment: @AndrewBro did this helped you?

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript

To solely select all `div`s with attribute `tab` you can use pure JavaScript like that:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div[tab]');
```

To perform some action on each of them do:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[tab]');

[].forEach.call(divs, function(element, index, array) {
  // Your code here
});
```

- `element` will match HTML element,
- `index` will match which element of all matched we are running our code for,
- `array` will contain all matched elements.

If you won't need any of those variables in your code, you can get rid of them.

### jQuery

jQuery way of selecting `div`s from your example:

```
$('div[tab]');
```

### Note

Also note that `tab` is not a valid attribute for `div`. If it had to be custom attribute, change it to `data-tab`. Or perhaps you meant global [`tabindex`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp) attribute?